# Mongoose - can't call model.find() in post findOneAndUpdate hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Summary**

In Mongoose have a post findOneAndUpdate hook and inside of this hook I need to query the database.  I'm trying to do a .find() on another model, however each time I do, I get the following error:

**Error**

```
TypeError: Users.find is not a function
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/benjilightstone/Coding/eSports-node-RESTful-API/api/models/fortniteUsers.js:29:32)
```

I have tried running the exact same .find() in one of my express routes and it works perfectly.  I have checked the require() for Users and it's imported correctly.  I have no idea why I'm getting this error and would love some help!

***Code***

**fortniteUsers.js (Model with post hook)**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Users = require("./users");
const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");
const statsFieldsSchema = require("./statsFields");

const fnUserPlatformSchema = {
  //this is so that have a unique entry for a username &platform combo
  fnUser: { type: String, require: true },
  platform: { type: String, enum: ["pc", "xb1", "psn"], require: true }
};
//TODO took out updated at because the record shouldn't get updated?
//TODO think about usecase of Fortnite user changing their username

const fortniteUserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // pass a javascript object that defines the schema
  fnUserPlatform: { type: fnUserPlatformSchema, unique: true, require: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, require: true },
  hasAccount: { type: Boolean, require: true, default: false },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, require: false },
  lifeTimeStats: { type: statsFieldsSchema, require: true }
});

fortniteUserSchema.post("findOneAndUpdate", async function(fortniteUser, next) {
  try {
    console.log("inside fortniteUser post hook", typeof fortniteUser._id);
    const fnUserId = String(fortniteUser._id);
    console.log("fnUserId", fnUserId);
    // const userId = await User.find({ fnUser: fnUserId });
    const userId = await Users.find({ fnUser: "5ccb08198f52f40117e950b3" });
    console.log("userId", userId);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error in post hook", err);
  }
});

fortniteUserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model("FortniteUser", fortniteUserSchema);
```

**users.js (User model imported in fortniteUsers.js)**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const FortniteUsers = require("./fortniteUsers");
require("mongoose-type-email");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // pass a javascript object that defines the schema
  fnUser: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "FortniteUser",
    require: true
  },
  eSportsUsername: { type: String, require: true },
  password: { type: String, require: true, minlength: 5 },
  email: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email, require: true, unique: true },
  ageConfirmed: { type: Boolean, require: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, require: true },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, require: false }
});

userSchema.pre("save", function() {
  console.log("inside pre save users.js");
  console.log("docToSave", this); // QUESTION:  how would I pass in req.body.fnUser
  FortniteUsers.findOne({
    fnUserPlatform: { username: req.body.fnUser, platform: "psn" }
  })
    .then(result => {
      console.log("result in pre", result);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log("error i expect", err));
});

userSchema.post("save", function(user) {
  //TODO where is user gettting passed from, I dont really understand this
  console.log("we're in post save ... ", user);

  FortniteUsers.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: user.fnUser },
    { $set: { hasAccount: true } },
    function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error in mongoose userSchema.post", err);
      }
    }
  );
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like the problem is because you require `fortniteUsers` and `users` in each other so one of them is not yet exported when call inside the other.

To verify this, you can `console.log(FortniteUsers)` and `console.log(Users)` after require them. You can see that `FortniteUsers` is `Model {FortniteUsers}` but `Users` is just `{}`.

You can solve it by moving this line `const FortniteUsers = require("./fortniteUsers");` to be after the exports in `users.js` (not sure this is the good way but it works).